# Send two or more parameters in a view based on functions with django

Tags: python, django, variables, web, backend

i am developing a webpage with django, but I was wondering if there is a way to send two or more parameters in a view based on functions. Like this:

```
def index(request):
    categoria = Clasificacion.objects.all()
    contexto = {'categoria':categoria}
    articulo = Articulo.objects.all()
    contexto1 = {'articulo':articulo}
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', contexto, contexto1)
```

As you can see, I am trying to send "contexto" and "contexto1" to the template, but it receives just one of them (just the "contexto").

This is the part of my urls.py for that function, if you need it:

```
url(r'^home', index, name='home'),
```

So, can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to send multiple contexts (which doesn't make sense anyway), you can send both parameters in a single context:

```
def index(request):
    categoria = Clasificacion.objects.all()
    articulo = Articulo.objects.all()

    contexto = {
        'categoria':categoria,
        'articulo':articulo
    }

    return render(request, 'home/index.html', contexto)
```